# Windows Server 2008 R2 + IIS 7: how to reject traffic for a given domain/port

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

We've got a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance running IIS 7 serving multiple websites / web services on multiple domains (all port 80 or 443).

We have a security issue with a specific subdomain/port, and I would like to configure the server not to respond on that subdomain/port combination at all (i.e., not even a TCP response...the `SYN` should receive no corresponding `ACK`, as if the server doesn't even exist).

I'm not an experienced network admin, and less so on Windows.  Using Microsoft Network Monitor, I can see that *something* is picking up the phone and responding with a 404:

[image]

The "process" field is blank, so I don't know what's actually picking up the phone.  I suspect it must be IIS, but there's no website configured to respond to this particular domain/port.  I thought perhaps the "Default Web Site" catches all unconfigured traffic, but when I set up failed request monitoring on the Default Web Site, I get no logs for it.

I suppose a firewall entry might do the job, but I would like to know how things actually work before going that route.  What is responding to this network request, and how do I find out?  And then can I configure that component to not respond to these requests?

UPDATE: per @Mass Nerder's comment, I ran `netstat -anb` and I get the following for port 80 (the port in question):

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    172.17.63.2:80         50.205.86.154:37961    ESTABLISHED
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    172.17.63.2:80         50.205.86.154:54097    ESTABLISHED
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    172.17.63.4:80         69.66.192.88:53898     ESTABLISHED
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    172.17.63.4:80         69.66.192.88:53899     ESTABLISHED
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    172.17.63.4:80         69.66.192.88:53900     ESTABLISHED
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
```

Comment: run `netstat -anb` to see what is listening on that port

Comment: Updated with `netstat -anb` results

Comment: Since the `-b` didn't give the owner information try `netstat -ano` which will hopefully give you the PID of the process and then you can use task manager to make that PID to the process name

Comment: I'm assuming the server is in the DMZ or on the net directly otherwise you could filter on the actual firewall.  Without a Destination I can't tell what you are trying to block.  Is it IP:80 traffic?  You're request of "not even a TCP response" would mean you would have to not have the port open on that IP at all, otherwise IIS will reply back.  If you are hosting multiple domains on the same IP:port combo then this isn't an option though.  So can you elaborate what "destination" you are trying to prevent responding?

Comment: @TheCleaner, I think you answered my question...other apps do need to respond on port 80 (via different domains/subdomains).  So it sounds like what I'm looking to do isn't possible.

Comment: Correct - I'll throw that in as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the server is in the DMZ or on the net directly otherwise you could filter on the actual firewall. Without a Destination I can't tell what you are trying to block. Is it IP:80 traffic? You're request of "not even a TCP response" would mean you would have to not have the port open on that IP at all, otherwise IIS will reply back.

f you are hosting multiple domains on the same IP:port combo then this isn't an option though.